# "\n" new line character loaded as " " string from DB

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Java web app using postgres and hibernate.

I have a column in table with text content which contains new line characters. I need to preserve them, but when I load the data from this column all new lines are replaced with " " character.

I don't have any clue where to start looking for the problem. Any ideas? Can it be some hibernate setting?

It is quite a framework involved in data loading, but I tried digging as close to real hibernate calls as possoble:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass)
resultEntities = (List<E>) criteria.list();
```

Here is the column definition

```
@Column(name = "definition", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
```

The Criteria itself does not contain something special.

Comment: Try to use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` instead of "\n" and see if it helps. It's supposed to provide a OS-independent new line character.

Comment: "but when I load the data from this column" <-- how do you load them? Code, please.